# Why does a Spark application fail with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to run a Spark application in Eclipse with JRE 1.8.0 and am facing the following exception. Why?

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
18/04/01 17:05:30 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
   at org.apache.spark.util.TimeStampedWeakValueHashMap.<init>(TimeStampedWeakValueHashMap.scala:42)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:277)
   at com.pooja.spark.training.sparkexamples.wordcount$.main(wordcount.scala:10)
   at com.pooja.spark.training.sparkexamples.wordcount.main(wordcount.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce$class
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   ... 4 more
```

Comment: can you share the code line where you are getting the error?

Comment: spark scala dependencies i am using are <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

*"Spark version 1.4.1"*?! That's old. Unless you know what you're doing, please upgrade to the latest in 1.x release chain or 2.3.0 if possible.

---

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class

The runtime exception is because you don't have Scala libraries available in your runtime environment (in the JVM's CLASSPATH). You have to tell Eclipse to use Scala as a dependency that has to be included in the JVM when running the Spark application.

I recommend using Eclipse with tools like [sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/) or [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage dependencies.

While we're at it, I also recommend trying out the Spark examples in [Apache Spark Examples](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html).

Comment: <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: @ jacek laskowski which spark version will go with scala 2.11.8

Comment: @pooja that's the beauty of using a build tool: if your project has a dependency on spark, you wouldn't have to worry about importing scala manually, because spark will come with a scala dependency (which is a good thing because you don't want a different version by accident)

Comment: i have defined scala and spark dependencies in my pom.xml file

Comment: i have upgraded my pom file to :<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: You have to update `pom.xml` and tell Eclipse that the file has been updated. If you don't refresh Eclipse (if it does not happen automatically), Eclipse won't notice the change. Can you take a screenshot or two of how you run a Spark application in Eclipse?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the current `pom.xml` and how you run the Spark application. Thanks!